# Program is stuck at NextMatch() when Regex.NextMatch is null

Tags: c#, regex, file

I'm trying to parse a large html file to extract specific elements but after it parses the last elements (Match.NextMatch is null) it never get out of `NextMatch()`, here is the code:

```
Match FrameMatcher = Regex.Match(File.ReadAllText(file.FileName), @"<td class=""tline""><p><a href=""#(.*?)_\[(.*?)]""  style=""font-family:Arial;font-size:10.0pt"">\1 \[\2]<\/a><\/p><\/td>", RegexOptions.Multiline|RegexOptions.Singleline);
                int frameCount = 0;
                while (FrameMatcher.Success)
                {
                    frameCount++;
                    FrameMatcher = FrameMatcher.NextMatch();
                }
                MessageBox.Show(frameCount.ToString());
```

Comment: Well firstly, you should use an HTML parsing library for this. Regex isn't really the way to go here.

Comment: A better way might be to use Regex.Matches().Count is all you want to do is display the number of matches.

Comment: I tried it with a light html file and it worked for me, so yes I think regular regex isn't the most performant way to parse a html file, do you guys have any recommandations for a html parser ?

Comment: I know this answer is old and it's good advice to use an HTML Parser, but I don't understand what's wrong with your code -- it looks good, specifically it uses `while (FrameMatcher.Success)`. I think the accepted answer might be misleading/mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an infinite loop.
try to change the while condition to something like:

```
while (FrameMatcher != null)
{
     frameCount++;
     FrameMatcher = FrameMatcher.NextMatch();
}
```

And as already mentioned, it would be better to parse the html file with an html parsing library rather than regex.

Comment: yes a html parser is the answer but I don't know any.

Comment: Try HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: I'll give it a try, Thank you!

Comment: Happy i could help

Comment: Actually won't **this code** cause the infinite loop? The return value of `NextMatch()` is never null, so the while condition `while (FrameMatcher !=null)` will always be satisfied = infinite loop. The official [C# example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match.nextmatch?view=net-8.0#examples) uses `while (FrameMatcher.Success)`. Here is [example code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rEsllH) which uses `.Success`, it works as expected. [This](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FwXFzk) uses `!=null`, and **WARNING** it crashes the browser tab.

Comment: @NateAnderson NextMatch() will always get the next matched element until it reaches the end of the matches, then it would return null and quit the loop.

Comment: I don't think so @MahdiBenaoun, NextMatch does not return null

Comment: @NateAnderson my apologies you’re right!

Comment: Thanks for acknowledging @MahdiBenaoun , that's why this answer is confusing -- it's just *wrong*. And it confuses me, your original question seems *correct*!

Comment: @NateAnderson I don’t remember why I marked it as a valid answer (just removed it)

Comment: Thanks @MahdiBenaoun , I think that's appropriate. Maybe you used an Html parser, which is a good suggestion.